# PostgreSQL - Rails Server Crashing on Start "Library not loaded...(LoadError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, osx-mountain-lion

I am setting up a Rails Project. Each time I go to start the server, I am getting a big error;

```
    rails server puma
warning: ignoring extraneous `ruby-' prefix in version `ruby-2.0.0-p247'
         (set by /Users/jamesnewman/shout_factory/.ruby-version)
/Users/jamesnewman/shout_factory/vendor/bundle/gems/pg-0.15.1/lib/pg.rb:4:in `require': dlopen(/Users/jamesnewman/shout_factory/vendor/bundle/gems/pg-0.15.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /Users/jamesnewman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/libruby.2.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/jamesnewman/shout_factory/vendor/bundle/gems/pg-0.15.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/jamesnewman/shout_factory/vendor/bundle/gems/pg-0.15.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle
```

To try and fix this, I have done;

1. Removed rvm for rbenv
2. Uninstalled and Re-Installed PG (with both Home Brew, and on the Gem Level)
3. Updated to ruby-2.0.0-p247 (as per the request of another dependency)

And many more attempts to fix that I have probably forgotten about. I have googled and tried almost every fix for something like this from different terminal commands, to full on switching from rvm to rbenv.

And just so I knew that it was this project that I was having a hard time with, and not something else, I started the server on a couple of my other projects and everything worked fine.

If anyone has any help on how to fix this, I would really appreciate it. If anyone needs to see maybe the gems I'm using or something else, I'd be more than happy to post it.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This issue was able to be resolved. If anyone else has this issue, it can be fixed. It might be different, but for me, I was able to fix it by uninstalling all of the gems and reinstalling and setting up the entire project/system again from scratch. It was something wrong that I did, but it was able to be fixed.

Hope this helps anyone who may have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue after downgrading PG from 14 to 13 due to port change. The solution that worked for me was to uninstall `pg` gem, then reinstall again.